# Цикл генерации случайного списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, циклы

имеется задача:

Анализ лотереи: напишите цикл, который проверяет, насколько сложно выиграть в смоделированной вами лотерее. Создайте список или кортеж с именем my_ticket . Напишите цикл, который продолжает генерировать комбинации до тех пор, пока не выпадет выигрышная комбинация. Выведите сообщение с информацией о том, сколько выполнений цикла понадобилось для получения выигрышной комбинации.

Я написал к ней код, но хотел бы узнать как можно его оформить покороче/полаконичнее?

```
from random import randint

my_ticket = [1,3,7,2,3]
count = 0
numbers = []
while my_ticket != numbers:
    count += 1
    for i in range(5):
        numbers.append(randint(1, 7))

    if my_ticket != numbers:
        numbers = []
    else:
        print(numbers)
        print(f'Количество итераций {count}')
```

А именно как можно сбрасывать список из неподходящих чисел кроме как :

```
   if my_ticket != numbers:
        numbers = []
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сравнение вообще не требуется, потому что оно уже есть в инициализации цикла while. Поэтому if можно смело убрать.

```
while my_ticket != numbers:
    numbers = []
    count += 1
    for i in range(5):
        numbers.append(randint(1, 7))

print(numbers)
print(f'Количество итераций {count}')
```

Answer (score 5):

Если совсем коротко, то как-то вот так:

```
from random import randint

my_ticket = [1,3,7,2,3]
count = 1
while my_ticket != [randint(1, 7) for _ in range(5)]:
    count += 1
print(f'Количество итераций {count}')
```

---

Или очень-очень коротко :)

```
from random import randint

my_ticket = [1,3,7,2,3]
print('Количество итераций', sum(1 for _ in iter(lambda: [randint(1, 7) for _ in range(5)], my_ticket)))
```

Comment: Т.е в этом месте [randint(1, 7) for _ in range(5)]: вы сразу внутри создаете список? А как называется такой способ?

Comment: Это называется [`list comprehension`](https://webdevblog.ru/kogda-ispolzovat-list-comprehension-v-python/).

Answer (score 2):

Можно так

```py
from random import randint
from itertools import count

my_ticket = [1,3,7,2,3]
numbers = []
for j in count(1):
    numbers = [randint(1, 7) for _ in my_ticket]
    if numbers == my_ticket:
        break
    
print(numbers)
print(f'Количество итераций {j}')
```

а можно без создания второго списка:

```py
from random import randint

my_ticket = [1,3,7,2,3]
count = 0
win = False 
while not win:
    count += 1
    win = True
    for i in my_ticket:
        if i != randint(1, 7):
            win = False
            break
    
print(my_ticket)
print(f'Количество итераций {count}')
```

Comment: Сложная запись, судя по всему  тут идет поиндексный подбор, что не совсем подходит под условие задачи.

Comment: @Yarachc, запись не сложная, все просто!